# JS Date&Time doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, date, time, clock

I've created a javascript to show date&time in Javascript, but it doesn't return anything
I've tried a lot of advises, but nothing worked.

HTML CODE

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var hr = today.getHours();
    var min = today.getMinutes();
    var sec = today.getSeconds();
    ap = (hr < 12) ? "<span>AM</span>" : "<span>PM</span>";
    hr = (hr == 0) ? 12 : hr;
    hr = (hr > 12) ? hr - 12 : hr;
    //Add a zero in front of numbers<10
    hr = checkTime(hr);
    min = checkTime(min);
    sec = checkTime(sec);
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + ap;
    
    var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
    var curWeekDay = days[today.getDay()];
    var curDay = today.getDate();
    var curMonth = months[today.getMonth()];
    var curYear = today.getFullYear();
    var date = curWeekDay+", "+curDay+" "+curMonth+" "+curYear;
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
    
    var time = setTimeout(function(){ startTime() }, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

```css
div {
 margin
    border-radius:15px;
    color:#ecf0f1;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:70px
}
```

```html
    <div id="clock"></div>
    <div id="date"></div>
```

Could I change this javascript code to show time from 5 different timezones?

Comment: Yes, there's no `return` statement in the function. Where exactly did you plan to use the return value? I mean you're not invoking the function, how do you know there's no return value?

Comment: You need to actually call the function startTime.

Comment: In your checkTime function, check the type of i, using:  if ( typeof i != "string" ) { i = String(i); }, then you can safely check its length with i.length < 2 then i = "0" + i;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order it works, it's important to call function **startTime**, so add this line to your javasrcipt code.

```
startTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I forgot about calling. Sorry.

Worked with

```
window.onload = function () {

'use strict';

setInterval(startTime, 500);
```